# Update através de outra tabela - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

estou com o seguinte problema:
Tenho uma tabela **rev_tasks** que contem id como chave,
e uma segunda tabela **rev_reviews** e tem como chave estrangeira **task_id**, apontando para a task, além disso tenho um campo (**revisado**) que indica se a review foi ou não revisada.

Na rev_task eu tenho um campo (**totalNRev**) que indica quantas reviews **NÃO** foram revisadas

neste momento que estou com problemas, tenho que fazer um update no banco para todas as tasks atualizando o campo totalNRev.

Vocês poderiam me dar sugestões ?
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: faca update utilizando join

Comment: Olá Victor, você poderia ser mais claro? o join ficaria no set ou no where ?

Comment: não entendi...  que você quer atualizar o campo totalNRev na tabela rev_task certo ? Ou campos de duas tabelas diferentes ao mesmo tempo, neste caso poderia utilizar join

Comment: isso mesmo, este campo é a contagem de todas as rev_reviews onde o revisado = 'Nao', além dessa condição tenho que atualizar apenas as rev_tasks que o id for igual ao task_id da tabela rev_reviews, deu pra sacar aí ?

Comment: vou postar uma resposta para voce verificar se atende sua necessidade, se sim **comente abaixo da resposta**

Comment: Olá Victor, consegui resolver o problema, coloquei como resposta a minha resolução, muito obrigado o//

Comment: ok irei remover a minha resposta então

Answer (score 0):

Então galera, consegui resolver aqui através deste update

```
update rev_tasks t inner join (select task_id, count(1) as qtd from rev_reviews where revisado = 'Nao' group by task_id) r on t.id = r.task_id set t.totalPen = r.qtd where t.id = r.task_id;
```